# Ubuntu 12.04 - Custom Quick Launcher Menu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have been using Ubuntu for few weeks now and I am have been trying to create custom menu which to add in the launcher.

Please, note that my version is 12.04 and I have not got any experience with Linux.

I have checked a lot articles and questions likes [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available), but have not been able to find what I am looking for.

I want to create a custom quick launcher menu and to add it the the standard launcher, but I want to add links to other programs or folders in it. For example:

1. A browsers menu - when it is open (with right mouse click on it), my browsers will be listed:

   - Chrome
   - Safari
   - Opera
   - Firefox

   I even may add their icons there.
2. Music menu - some shortcuts to my favorite music folders.

Comment: What 'desktop' are you using? Could you take a screenshot of your user interface?

Comment: @Padenton, I am talking about the left navigation bar of unity. When application is opened it is shown there, and you have also there some shortcuts. For more screenshots you can check the link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily fixed using "Drawers". First, you should upgrade to 12.12.2 version.

This is link with more information of how "Drawers" are used:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/drawers-12122-brings-improved-loading.html